# Why echo and print command would generate arrow symbol(->) in shell script?

Tags: shell, ksh

It is a little tricky that I run a ksh script and there are "echo" and "print" commmands in it. and the output contains arrow symbol ->. like:

```
->   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
->                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
-> 
  0  4374    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0  4374    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
101  4374    0     0  101  4374      0   2934  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  4072
100  4642  134   268  101  4374    152   2491  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3264

-> This is FLAG!!!
   stty: standard input: Invalid argument
   stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

code snippet:
it would generate -> in output in  /data/home/user/bin/pushfile.sh /tmp/$ISSUE.$p4Cur $RUN_ENV | awk   '{print "\t" $0}' 2>&1 > $tmpLog

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 if [[ $ENV != "production" ]]
 then
    . $HOME/bin/getenv $RUN_ENV >> $RUN_LOGFILE
    if [[ ! -n $FILE_HOME ]]
    then
    echo "FILE_HOME could not be null"
    exit 1
    fi
    cd $FILE_HOME
    cat /tmp/$TICKET.$p4Cur | while read LINE
    do
    p4 sync -f "$LINE" 2>&1 > $tmpLog
            rc=$?
            cat $tmpLog | tee -a $RUN_LOGFILE
            if [[ $rc -gt 0 ]]
            then
            echo "Failed to sync file"
            exit $rc
            fi
    done
 fi

 if [[ $ENV != "production" ]]
 then
     echo "This is FLAG!!!"
    /data/home/user/bin/pushfile.sh /tmp/$ISSUE.$p4Cur $RUN_ENV | awk   '{print "\t" $0}' 2>&1 > $tmpLog

    cat $tmpLog | tee -a $RUN_LOGFILE

    errormsg=`grep "ERROR" $tmpLog `
    erc=$?
    if [[ $erc == 0 ]];then
            echo "Failed to run    /data/home/user/bin/pushfile.sh/tmp/$ISSUE.$p4Cur $BUILD_ENV ! script terminate!" 
            exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: could you provided your ksh script?

Comment: Perhaps you started the script in the background and hit Enter a view times waiting for output. When your command prompt looks like `->`, this prompt can be mixed with the output of your script.

Comment: @Mustafa, thanks for your reply. I just attach some snippet of that script where problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could be solution;

first run this;

```
stty sane
```

and then run your script;

In man stty;

```
stty changes and prints terminal line settings.

sane   same  as cread -ignbrk brkint -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iutf8 -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh
              -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke, all special characters to their default values
```

if not working, could you provide;

```
stty -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Two guesses:

1. The code sources this line containing `$RUN_ENV`.  We don't know what
   that is. Stdout is captured into `$RUN_LOGFILE`, stderr is not sepcified and goes to the terminal.

   `. $HOME/bin/getenv $RUN_ENV >> $RUN_LOGFILE`
2. This construct redirects all of stderr (fd 2) to the screen, and the normal `p4` (Perforce perchance?) to `$tmpLog`

   `p4 sync -f "$LINE" 2>& 1 > $tmpLog`

   If you want to capture both stdout & stderr into the file, switch the two around:

   ... `> $tmpLog 2>& 1`

In short, there are two commands that can produce any kind of output messing up your screen.
Find out which it is, and divert that output to a proper sink.